# Webpack Minified and Unminified Js and Css

Tags: javascript, webpack

Here's the file structure of what I want:

```
- dist
  - js
    - jPlayer.js
    - jPlayer.min.js
  - css
    - skins
      - sleek.css
      - sleek.min.css
```

Here's my webpack.config.js

```
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';
import OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin from 'optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';
import webpack from 'webpack';

const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

export default {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    'jPlayer.js': './build.js',
    'jPlayer.min.js': './build.js',
    'sleek.css': './src/less/skins/sleek.less',
    'sleek.min.css': './src/less/skins/sleek.less'
  },
  output: {
    path: './dist/',
    filename: '[name]',
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader',
          'css-loader?importLoaders=1' +
          '!postcss-loader' +
          '!less-loader'),
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name]'),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      include: /\.min\.js$/,
    }),
    new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
      assetNameRegExp: /\.min\.css$/
    })
  ],
  postcss: () => [autoprefixer],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
};
```

This currently outputs

```
- dist
  - jPlayer.js
  - jPlayer.min.js
  - sleek.css
  - sleek.min.css
```

UglifyJs also keeps mangling my sleek.css file like this:

[image]

How do I do this?

Which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UglifyJS was the problem here, for some reason it messes with css files even though it has JS in it's name which is just stupid.

BabiliPlugin worked much better as it didn't mess with css files.

```
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';
import OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin from 'optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';
import BabiliPlugin from 'babili-webpack-plugin';

export default {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    'js/jPlayer.js': './src/index.js',
    'js/jPlayer.min.js': './src/index.js',
    'css/skins/sleek.css': './src/less/skins/sleek.less',
    'css/skins/sleek.min.css': './src/less/skins/sleek.less',
  },
  output: {
    path: './dist/',
    filename: '[name]',
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
          plugins: ['transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader',
          'css-loader?importLoaders=1' +
          '!postcss-loader' +
          '!less-loader'),
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000',
      },
      {
        test: /\.jpg$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name]'),
    new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
      assetNameRegExp: /\.min\.css$/,
    }),
    new BabiliPlugin({}, {
      test: /\.min\.js$/,
    }),
  ],
  postcss: () => [autoprefixer],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `output` config to:

```
output: {
    path: './dist/',
    filename: 'js/[name]',
}
```

And `ExtractTextPlugin`'s config to:

```
new ExtractTextPlugin('./css/[name].css')
```